# Overlay analysis of two raster by attribute?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, overlay

I have two rasters (one showing land use and the other showing soil texture). I'd like to find the areas where there is a specific land use on a specific soil texture.

Is there a way to overlay two rasters but with a boolean statement or some kind of qualifier?

I have tried zonal statistics but each attribute table for my rasters have multiple columns and I only want to compare values between two of the columns (soil texture in one table and land use type in the other table).

Comment: You will need to use Raster Calculator with the Con function. What calculation are you trying to perform? This sort of overlay is best done as vector.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson So would I need to convert the raster to polygon? The ideal outcome would be a map showing where farmland occurs on clay soil (soil class 1). I'm not necessarily doing a calculation but looking for the intersection.

Comment: con(soil_type = 1,land_use) will give you all the land uses on soil type 1. If you want to compile a table of all the land uses and soil types then that should be done as a vector, if you want to get the land uses for a soil type (or types) then use con in raster calculator to extract.

Comment: It is COMBINE in spatial analyst.http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000083000000  it works on integer rasters

Comment: Fair enough @FelixIP, that's a new one to me. I think it's safe to put that in as an answer, it does exactly what's required.

Comment: Nah. Few times already I was told off for shorties

Comment: Just be a bit more descriptive @FelixIP, and add a few related issues. I've expanded your comment to an answer so future users can search.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson You could also of course use nested or multi-condition con statements in the raster calculator to do it with a single operation, just as the Combine tool.

Answer (score 1):

As Felix is unwilling to answer this I will have a go.

The tool to intersect two (integer) rasters is [Combine](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000007r000000.htm) which will merge the attributes of up to 20 rasters.

It is unclear from the tool help what happens to raster attributes other than value, should they be built, after running this tool but from the graphic it appears only the value will be copied to the new rasters' attribute table. If you have soil type or land use descriptions in the raster you may need to re-establish them using [Add Field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000047000000) then [join with the land use and soil types](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) and copy the descriptions with [calculate field](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004m000000).

It would be best for the output raster to be of the type Esri GRID if there are more than 255 values as the number of unique combinations between the rasters cannot exceed 65535.